# Xamarin.Android - Create Multiple Databases with SQLite.NET ORM

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I had two databases in my app,which i created with the help of the SQLiteOpenHelper class.I decided to do away with the SQLiteOpenHelper and just create the databases using the SQLite component only.I have a databaseHandler class where i create the dbs and the tables.The problem is i can only seem to create one database.If i add a second database name to be created,i get a black screen on start up and then it crashes.It seems to me like the two dbs can't coexist in the same location.I'm not sure how to solve the issue though.

```
namespace com.Sample.Database
{
public class DatabaseHandler 
{

private string COMPANY_DATABASE_NAME;

private string USER_DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
private string COMPANY_DATABASE_PATH;
private string USER_DATABASE_PATH;
private int databaseVersion = 3;
private SQLiteConnection companyDatabaseConnection;
private SQLiteConnection userDatabaseConnection;
private static DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
Context context;

//Constructor
private DatabaseHandler (Context context)
{
try
{
//this.COMPANY_DATABASE_NAME = "company" + "v" + this.databaseVersion + ".db";

    string dataDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

     USER_DATABASE_PATH = System.IO.Path.Combine (dataDirectory, USER_DATABASE_NAME);

     COMPANY_DATABASE_PATH = System.IO.Path.Combine (dataDirectory, COMPANY_DATABASE_NAME);


    this.context = context;

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

            logTable.Exception (context, ex);

}


public static DatabaseHandler GetInstance(Context context)
   {
       if (dbHandler == null) {
             dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler (context);
      }

return dbHandler;
}
  public void initialize()
   {
       try
       {


    this.userDatabaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection(USER_DATABASE_PATH);

    this.userDatabaseConnection.CreateTable<UserTable> ();


    this.InsertData();

  //            this.companyDatabaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection     (COMPANY_DATABASE_PATH);
//
  //            this.companyDatabaseConnection .CreateTable<RecordsTable> ();

}
      catch(Exception e)
     {
                logTable.Exception (context, ex);


        }
   }
```

}

The crashing happens when i uncomment the line where i'm assigning a name to the company database:

```
//this.COMPANY_DATABASE_NAME = "company" + "v" + this.databaseVersion + ".db";
```

And gives me the  following output:

```
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref GTI.Thales.Droid[0x7be12eb8] ->  SQLite[0x7c389c38]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref SQLite[0x7c389c38] -> mscorlib[0x73ac7ca8]: 10
[Mono] GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 0 num_hash_entries 0 sccs size 0 init 0.00ms df1 0.00ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links   0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 147.43ms, total 147.98ms, bridge 0.34ms promoted 448K major 688K los 0K
[Mono] GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 0 num_hash_entries 0 sccs size 0 init   0.00ms df1 0.00ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.00ms setup-cb 0.00ms free-data 0.00ms links   0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 141.11ms, total 141.66ms, bridge 0.21ms promoted 0K major 688K los 0K
[Mono] Warning: Degraded allocation.  Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists.
```

I already increased the nursery-size to 8 but i get the error still.

Comment: Unrelated: `catch(Exception ex){ ex.ToString(); }` This doesn't do anything; you convert the exception to a string, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: I'm actually saving them to the database as well.That was an oversight @Colonel Thirty Two

Comment: I don't have a good answer but why two dbs? Why not tables for model1, model2, model3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

this.COMPANY_DATABASE_NAME = "company" + "v" + this.databaseVersion.ToString() + ".db";

Comment: Brian Robillard I already had made this change later in the code but that wasn't the source of the bug.It was a circular dependency caused by some two classes which would sort of initiate each other.Thanks for your response though.I appreciate it